# Adding to WooCommerce Product Price based on Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a WooCommerce Simple product called Tour and tour price is 500
I have a couple of advanced custom fields, for example Hotel Dropdown and Departure Point Dropdown. Hotel Dropdown has 3 hotels and each hotel has a price. Similarly, Departure Point Dropdown has a few options and each option has a price.

What I am trying to achieve is when you select a hotel on the product details page, hotel price should be added to the product price, e.g. product price 500 plus hotel price 200, so product should show a total of 700. Similarly if you select a departure point, its price should be added to the the total. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Looking for something like this http://exthemes.net/wootour/product/bangkok-pattaya-3-star-hotel/

Comment: Haven't built the site yet, we are still in the planning phase.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063615/dynamic-price-calculation-based-on-custom-field-in-woocommerce/49066964#49066964 … But if your plan to make something like in your linked web site, you should better use woocommerce booking plugin (or other similar booking plugins).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still unable to achieve this. I have updated my question making it more clear.